# Custom css is not applying to bootstrap subtheme

Tags: theming

I followed the step by step to create a subtheme of bootstrap theme. Now, I am not able to apply my custom css to my page.

I took the below steps:

A) Downloaded  Bootstrap project (7.x-3.0). Placed the bootstrap folder in sites/all/themes/.

B) Downloaded jQuery Update project, which is required by Bootstrap. In ../admin/config/development/jquery_update and set the default jQuery version to 1.10.

C) From bootstrap folder, moved the bootstrap_subtheme folder to sites/all/themes/ and name it bootsub

D) In bootsub directory, renamed the bootstrap_subtheme.info.starterkit file to bootsub.info. I edited the content and it looks as below:

```
name = bootsub
description = A Bootstrap Sub-theme.
core = 7.x
base theme = bootstrap
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Regions
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


regions[navigation]     = 'Navigation'
regions[header]         = 'Top Bar'
regions[highlighted]    = 'Highlighted'
regions[help]           = 'Help'
regions[content]        = 'Content'
regions[sidebar_first]  = 'Primary'
regions[sidebar_second] = 'Secondary'
regions[footer]         = 'Footer'
regions[page_top]       = 'Page top'
regions[page_bottom]    = 'Page bottom'


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Stylesheets
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


stylesheets[all][] = css/bootsub.css


; For information on choosing the desired method, please read the Drupal
; Bootstrap sub-theme "how-to" documentation:
; https://drupal.org/node/1978010


; ;----------------------------------
; ; METHOD 1: Bootstrap Source Files
; ;----------------------------------
; 
; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; ;; Scripts
; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; 
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/css/style.css'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/affix.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/alert.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/button.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/carousel.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/collapse.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/modal.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/tooltip.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/popover.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/tab.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/transition.js'
;
; ; Disable BootstrapCDN if using Bootstrap source files in your sub-theme.
; settings[bootstrap_cdn] = ''


; ;-------------------------
; ; METHOD 2: Bootstrap CDN
; ;-------------------------
;
; Method 2 uses BootstrapCDN, the only thing you might need to provide here
; is overrides to Bootstrap theme settings. Copy them here from the base theme
; to override.
```

E) I enabled the bootsub subtheme.

F) Sites/all/themes/bootsub/css, I added bootsub.css file. I added some styling in the css file.

G) I inspected my page using chrome and I see that styling is not coming from bootsub.css file and instead it is coming from

"netdna.bootstrapcdn.com.......bootstrap.min.css.."

Do you know why custom css file is not applying the styling on my page?

*Further Notes*

- Using CDN method
- Cache has been cleared
- Aggregation is OFF
- "View source" in browser does not show bootsub.css had been loaded
- Using shared hosting

---

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279120/using-bootstrap-cdn-with-drupal/29789222#29789222?newreg=1f8d029638e84eb88467db9f871e3bbf)

I found the link which does not allow me to comment. Link says:

> I had the same issue few days ago and I fixed with the template
>   preprocess function. Just put the following function inside your
>   template.php
>
> ```
> function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {  
>  drupal_add_css('/PATH_TO_THEME/custom-style.css'); }
> ```

I tried to follow the above steps and did not work. I have the subtheme in sites>all>themes. In sites>all>themes>subtheme, I have template.php. I added the below code in template.php:

```
<?php
function subtheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_css('/sites/all/themes/subtheme/css/subtheme.css');
}

?>
```

Do you know if i followed the steps correctly or anything else you would like to recommend to resolve this issue?

[site](http://chartersdc.com/)

Comment: did you clear cache after adding your css to the .info file?

Comment: Yes by following this step: config > performance > clear all cache.

Comment: one other thought, try to disable the CSS aggregation and see if it's comes up

Comment: Hi, Drupol. The CSS from the CDN is supposed to be there, else your site won't look very Bootstrappy. :) Your custom CSS file should load after this file and also after Bootstrap Theme's 'overrides.css' file. Did you do an in-page search for your "bootsub.css" in Source mode (View Source)?

Comment: I added my site url above. I did see the source code and I dont see my css. I thought I did follow the steps. If you could help, it will be so great.

Comment: What server r u using? On what platform? Mb some file permissions do not allow your server to read bootsub.css?

Comment: I have my drupal installed in cpanel of hosting server. Also, my css aggregation is already turned off.

Comment: Going through the source code of the site you have provided, I find that the name of the theme you have enabled is **chartersdc** and not _bootsub_. I see that the css _chartersdc.css_ is called from the theme path. I dont know if this is where you are wrong..

Comment: Another thing is to look at theme advanced settings and disable cdn

Comment: Thanks ar7max. I disabled the cdn and I do see my css now. I enabled it again because my site does not look good without cdn.

Answer (score 2):

In the Theme settings Under Bootstrap Settings, Go to Advanced -> BootstrapCDN and choose Disabled from the dropdown.

Then in the theme info file uncomment the Method 1 section. Download the bootstrap files from [Bootstrap Download](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and extract it to the subtheme folder. The extracted folder should be named - bootstrap and should contain all the necessary bootstrap js, css files.

You may get more info from this link [Bootstrap sub-theming "how to"](https://www.drupal.org/node/1978010)

Comment: I thought you can subtheme using the method1 and 2. Your above step is for method1? I rather use method2. For method2, It says "Method 2: Bootstrap CDN
This method is rather simple. You don't have to do anything unless you wish to override the default Bootstrap base theme settings. If so, just un-comment the
lines pertaining to Method 2.

Edit the provided ./css/style.css file to your liking."

Comment: Then, I hope you have defined your CSS correctly. I did find this troublesome in my other projects and used Method 1 instead

Comment: So, now what would be the solution to my problem?